# Socat keeps waiting for input from stdin

Tags: socat

I need to run this command on Mac OS X El Capitan. I found it on this guide about [Eclipse Che](https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/usage-docker-server-for-mac#running-che-as-a-server). However, when I try to do that, `socat` keeps waiting for input from stdin.

```
$ socat -d TCP-LISTEN:2376,range=127.0.0.1/32,reuseaddr,fork UNIX:/var/run/docker.sock
I'm writing here, and I don't know why socat let me do this

^C$
```

I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to return to the prompt. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author probably never tried it. [The manual](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#OPTION_FORK) says this about the `fork` option:

> After establishing a connection, handles its channel in a child process and keeps the parent process attempting to produce more connections, either by listening or by connecting in a loop (example).

That means `socat` will *not* fork before starting the main listen loop.

The `-d` option just increases verbosity (as in `debug`).

tl;dr: `socat` can’t do that.

The source tree contains this helper script to launch `socat` in the background. You can adapt it to your purposes. *I did not write this script!*

```
#! /bin/sh
# source: daemon.sh
# Copyright Gerhard Rieger 2001
# Published under the GNU General Public License V.2, see file COPYING

# This script assumes that you create group daemon1 and user daemon1 before.
# they need only the right to exist (no login etc.)

# Note: this pid file mechanism is not robust!

# You will adapt these variables
USER=daemon1
GROUP=daemon1
INIF=fwnonsec.domain.org
OUTIF=fwsec.domain.org
TARGET=w3.intra.domain.org
INPORT=80
DSTPORT=80
#
INOPTS="fork,setgid=$GROUP,setuid=$USER"
OUTOPTS=
PIDFILE=/var/run/socat-$INPORT.pid
OPTS="-d -d -lm"    # notice to stderr, then to syslog
SOCAT=/usr/local/bin/socat

if [ "$1" = "start" -o -z "$1" ]; then

    $SOCAT $OPTS tcp-l:$INPORT,bind=$INIF,$INOPTS tcp:$TARGET:$DSTPORT,bind=$OUTIF,$OUTOPTS </dev/null &
    echo $! >$PIDFILE

elif [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then

    /bin/kill $(/bin/cat $PIDFILE)
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`socat` connects the input/output of two addresses. Of the two addresses you provided (`TCP-LISTEN` and `UNIX`) none use the standard input/output, so your typing on the console sends nothing to `socat`. (One of the addresses would have to be `STDIO` or `STDIN` to accept your keyboard input from *stdin*).

Furthermore, [`man socat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) or `socat -h` reveals that `UNIX:` does not exist, but others do namely:  `UNIX-CLIENT:`, `UNIX-CONNECT:`, `UNIX-LISTEN:`, `UNIX-RECV:`, `UNIX-RECVFROM:`. Maybe that option exists on your vestion of `socat` (since the post is more than 1 year old...).

Also, without looking too much into detail on those options, remember that `socat` connects the *output* of one address with the *input* of another; and that in general this is bidirectional (output-to-input as well as input-to-output). So whatever is on the other end of the Unix socket (an Eclipse process?) would use the socket/file to both read and write.

So, if you're trying to connect a TCP port on 127.0.0.1:2376 to a filename (acting as a Unix socket), then the data will likely only be passed on as long as the sockets are open. I did not test - but you can run a "fake" listener to your Unix socket with another process, e.g. (1)

```
socat -d UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/docker.sock STDIO
```

and then have "your" TCP mediator as for example (2)

```
socat -d TCP-LISTEN:2376,range=127.0.0.1/32,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

(possibly adding the options `-x -v` at the start, to display the hexdump of data passing through). Finally, "simulate" the TCP client connecting to the TCP port with (3)

```
socat -d STDIO TCP:127.0.0.1:2376
```

In the end, stop (1) and (3). Hope that helps.